# Reset button don't work for select box

Tags: php, html, reset

I have select  box like this

```
    <select class="_55" name="call_info[main_service_id]" id="main_service">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <?php
      $main_service_object->get_mainservice_selected_option ( $main_service_id );
    ?>
   </select>
```

but when i click reset button list box didn't reset

reset button code:

```
<div class="actions-left">
<input type="reset">
</div>
```

so how can i reset select box using reset button?

Comment: Is the `select` in the same form as the reset button?

Comment: Is it wrapped in a form?

Answer (score 0):

The reset button is really on the way out, because it's rarely useful and often confusing.

If your select element has a default value, the reset button restores the select to that default. To confirm that it's working, select something else and hit reset.